# From a developer perspective what is the differnce between HVCP and Communities?

Tags: community, customer-portal, hvcp

Since new sfdc customers cant use HVCP anymore, I want to do a similar app to ones I have built with portal, what are the key difference here? Anything I cant do anymore? Anything new I can do?

Comment: This is a pretty big question and I'm not sure you'll get a comprehensive answer here. The products are quite different! I'd recommend going through the Communities guide to get a feel for the differences. Pricing has also changed quite a bit.

Comment: Thanks, I read the guide, but it seems completely focused on admin/end user experience and not much on development, is there a communities dev guide?

Comment: Not per se, but actual development (apex/triggers/VF etc) is exactly the same. I'm assuming the guide you found was this one? http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf

Comment: That was not the one I read, much more helpful, so from what I can tell it looks like I can do pretty much everything I could do before, but the 10 custom object limitation...

Comment: Yeah it's a limitation but customers can "purchase" the right to more than 10 objects. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on communities, but I can compare high volume customer portal with the now-deprecated customer portal license.

High volume customer portal users are something like 25% the cost, per user, of customer portal users. In exchange for this they aren't able to take advantage of sharing. Instead they're governed by much simpler permission grants that are defined on the customer portal setup page. Since you're using HVCP today I don't think I need to elaborate too much on that feature.

Instead of that customer portal (and I'm pretty sure communities) users get to work with normal sharing, that is they follow the org-wide defaults (although note that there's now separate defaults for internal and external users) and sharing rules, be they apex, criteria, or hierarchical, do impact their ability to view/edit records.

I believe there's also some system permissions that aren't available to high volume customer portal users, but off the top of my head I don't know what they are. The sharing settings were by far the most key difference between the two types of licenses.

Comment: So is HVCP still supported? I thought it was the same thing as customer portal...

Comment: Supported? Yes, but I believe it's not being sold to customers who don't already have at least some licenses for it (but existing customers can buy more... I think). Customer portal and community should be remarkably similar permissions wise, but with the added community features, like chatter, on top of the community license.

Comment: What about the 10 custom entity limit? Is there any work around for that?